# Unity-Dash Problem

Tags: 12.04, unity, nvidia, unity-dash

I have an *Asus x64J Laptop with 2 graphic cards (intel + nvidia)*. I installed Bumblebee to play games but since then my launcher looks different.

[image]

I want that part in the circle straight like on the top and in the middle, not compressed.

Can someone give me any idea of how to fix it? thx!

Answer (score 0):

You have too many icons on your dock. 2 solutions here :

- **Remove some icons you don't need** :

  *Right click on the icon > remove from launcher*

  [image: remove icon]
- **Reduce the icon-size** :

  1) Install Ubuntu-Tweak :

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
  ```

  2) Open Ubuntu-Tweak and look for the feature that allows you to change the icon-size of the dock.

  [image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But before i used Bumblebee it was all straight. I had the same amount of icons and just could scroll up and down without compressing it. That was much more comfortable because it remembered the exact position. Any ideas?

Comment: No, not right now :/